# AWS .NET SDK throws "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" when trying to get secret from AWS Secrets Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-net, aws-secrets-manager

I am simply trying to retrieve a secret from AWS Secrets Manager using the .NET SDK. The following is deployed to us-east-2 and the instance profile has the appropriate policy attached. I verified that permissions are configured properly by retrieving the secret with the cli.

```
using(var client = new AmazonSecretsManagerClient(RegionEndpoint.USEast2))
{
    var secret = client.GetSecretValue(new GetSecretValueRequest { SecretId = "asecret" });
}
```

After a minute or two, I get the following error.

```
Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException: A WebException with status SendFailure was thrown. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpHandler`1.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Unmarshaller.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.WebExceptionHandler.HandleException(IExecutionContext executionContext, WebException exception)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.ProcessException(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RuntimePipeline.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
   at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceClient.Invoke[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request, IMarshaller`2 marshaller, ResponseUnmarshaller unmarshaller)
   at Amazon.SecretsManager.AmazonSecretsManagerClient.GetSecretValue(GetSecretValueRequest request)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am from AWS .NET SDK team.  We are aware of this problem and are actively working on it.

The root problem seems to be that the HTTP client underneath fails to open HTTPS connection because either the host machine or the .NET framework you are using does not support TLS1.1 or 1.2 by default.

Comment: Thank you! I'm using 4.5.2. When I upgrade to 4.6.1 it works fine!

Comment: this suddenly started without us making any changes to the server side. What can we do?

Comment: @Steven Kang https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65939779/aws-ses-throws-amazonserviceexception-sporadically-unable-to-read-data-from-the